# how can i improve a current engine by redesigning internals such as pistons , ...etc?

Tags: design, automotive-engineering, car

i am designing a new car and planning to use an existing engine, my field is aerospace engineering so i have a good knowledge in machine design and thermodynamics, at first where can i find the technical specs of an engine other than disassembling and figuring out needed information? secondly, what are the good software that are suitable for individual?

edit: looks like some people don't understand what is written above, the question is:

where do i obtain specifications, data, blueprints, whatever of an engine, for example GM's LS3 or Honda K20?

know one of the users below told me to purchase a workshop manual, i will appreciate any additional info.

thank you for your time.

Comment: this is overly broad. This is not a discussion site, you need to pose specific answerable qusstions

Comment: Not gonna read past the sloppiness.  -1 for thumbing your nose at the volunteers here, and closing since I don't know what is being asked.  You wouldn't hand in homework like this, and your teachers are paid to read it.  We are all volunteers here.  Go away until you can show some respect.

Comment: i'm not a student in the first place, so don't accuse me with things you don't have knowledge about! all i wanted to know is where to obtain the specifications of an existing design so i can brake my way through it.

Comment: "I" is always uppercase in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design a stroker kit - first pick an engine where there is room to change the distance the piston travels - most engines are now designed with interference ie the piston and the valves occupy the same space but at different times.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but how do i know these information?

Comment: Buy a manufacturer’s workshop manual for the donor car - ie the one that uses the engine you want and read the chapter on the engine at least twice before you even think of picking up a spanner or any other tool...

Comment: Hesham, what is your design objective for the engine you wish to "improve"? more power, less weight, better economy, or what?

Comment: @niels my design is an ultra light weight car, meaning my focus will be more into 4 cylinder engines, most existing engines are little bit low on power so yes, the main objective is adding power to a light weight engine

Comment: There are some very high output 4 cyl engines already available - what have you looked at so far? Which manufacturers? Lotus?

Comment: there's a very good one in the Honda S2000 as well.

Comment: Yes I have some choices, mainly the Honda k24(≈290lb) easy to get, Honda k20 (≈270lb) little bit harder to find with higher price, also I am considering Subaru' s FA20 that used in the brz. For the s2000 engine it is a very good engine but I won't find it in my country since the car didn't went on sale.